# All groups not displayed with gitlab API

Tags: python, gitlab

I want to retrieve all subgroups from a group but it appears that some subgroups are not shown
*NB : it is not a problem of pagination since I only have 8 sugroups and I only get 6 of them*

```py
import gitlab
gl = gitlab.Gitlab('http://git-url', private_token='xxxxx')
for i in gl.groups.get(id=11).subgroups.list():
    group=gl.groups.get(id=i.id)
    print(i.name + " " + str(group.projects.list()))
```

Comment: is the private token tied to an admin account? It needs to be if you want it to show everything

Comment: that's probably the issue ... sorry